# Need Help Adding Custom Class To Application Settings

Tags: c#, winforms, settings

I am attempting to use the built in application settings to store a user context (i.e. currently logged in user) to my Winform application.  However, when I right-click on my project, click on properties, and then click browse for the type, the classes in my project are not an option.  I have two other projects in my solution and the classes in those projects are available.  Can anyone tell me why the classes in my project are not available to add to the application properties?  I guess that I could create another project to manage the user context but, our security is very simple and I'd prefer not to do that.  Also, I know that I could use dependency inject to pass the user context object around but, again this is a very simple security model that just needs to know which user is logged in so that transactions and audit trails can be properly recorded.  Thanks in advance.

BTW, I just created a new project and made sure that my project has a dependency on it.  Then, I checked to see if the classes that I added to it were available types in the application settings and they were not.  There has to be something simple that I am missing since the classes in my other projects are available to store as application properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you have to create another project to store a custom class.  I was able to accomplish what I was trying to do by performing the following steps:

1) Create another project
2) Move my user security classes to that project 
3) Add a reference from my project to the new user security project 
4) Clean my project 
5) Rebuild my project 
6) Open application settings 
7) Click browse and select type from my user security project